# how to set an existing c# resource as default resource in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've imported a project but when I import it the project has been converted by visual studio 2010.

My trouble is that VS is not recognizing the resource file and it's translations as the default resource file.

One of the consequences is that when I add a new language, VS is not adding the resource as satellite ...

How do I set the resource file as default resource again ?

Up to now I manually edit the Csproj in order to add my localized resource file.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unload the csproj and edit the xml for each language this way:

```
<Compile Include="Resources\Resource.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resource.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Resources\Resource.en-US.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resource.en-US.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Notice that I've moved all resources files into the Resource folder, if this is not your case remove `Resources\` from xml. For each resx you should set the `access modifier` as `public` as well.

Comment: In my case it's one cs and various localized resx ... If I compare to your sample the places are also inverted : it includes the resx and depend on the cs file ....

Comment: What type of project do you have? it's asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete resource file. Then right click on your project, choose Add an existing item and select your .resx file. May be this would work.